What's the relation between an SQL query and max_stack_depth?
Most questions about max_stack_depth are about how to bypass it, or increase it, etc.  I'm aware the default limit is 2MB and it cannot be set higher than ulimit -s. I would like to know how exactly Postgres determines that a query is over said limit.
Is it the number of nodes in an explain plan? Number of characters in the raw SQL query, after parameters, with or without bound parameters? etc.
E.g. I would like to take a query such as
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table 
WHERE x IN (1, 2, 3);

and translate that to a numerical (byte) value which would tell me how far from the max_stack_depth I am.

PostgreSQL regularly runs the function stack_is_too_deep(), which does something simple:

it declares an automatic variable (which is on the stack)

it uses pointer arithmetic to calculate the distance from another static global variable (that was initialized on the stack when the process started)


/*
 * Stack base pointer -- initialized by PostmasterMain and inherited by
 * subprocesses (but see also InitPostmasterChild).
 */
static char *stack_base_ptr = NULL;

[...]

bool
stack_is_too_deep(void)
{
    char        stack_top_loc;
    long        stack_depth;

    /*
     * Compute distance from reference point to my local variables
     */
    stack_depth = (long) (stack_base_ptr - &stack_top_loc);

    /*
     * Take abs value, since stacks grow up on some machines, down on others
     */
    if (stack_depth < 0)
        stack_depth = -stack_depth;

    /*
     * Trouble?
     *
     * The test on stack_base_ptr prevents us from erroring out if called
     * during process setup or in a non-backend process.  Logically it should
     * be done first, but putting it here avoids wasting cycles during normal
     * cases.
     */
    if (stack_depth > max_stack_depth_bytes &&
        stack_base_ptr != NULL)
        return true;

    return false;
}

I don't think there is a way to access that information via SQL, short of writing a C extension.

Thanks for the answer! Bummed there's no way to access this information as part of some EXPLAIN option, but I guess it's an extremely limited use case.
So my understanding is that it's literally about the size of all variables that got declared (and unfreed) in the lifetime of a PID, of which there is one per query (normally). In fact I wonder how that works for parallel queries? But that's another topic.

I think you misunderstand. This is just about the stack, so it is automatic variables and, most of all, function calls. So if you have a function that calls a function that calls a function, each time the stack grows. If you return from the function, the stack shrinks again. You really only get trouble with the stack depth if you have an endless recursion, and the point of the PostgreSQL parameter is that you get a nice error before you hit a system limit.

I ran into this error before when I had too many items in my IN list, which is why I used it as an example. Does this imply recursive calls under the hood?

Normally not; strange.

I'll create another post later with an example, I'll tag you there. Thanks again!
